# Repeated operations on $(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each pair of integers $(a,b)$, define the sequence $S_{(a,b)}$ as:

If $a_{n-1} < b_{n-1}$ then $(a_{n},b_{n}) = (2a_{n-1},b_{n-1}+1)$; otherwise if $b_{n-1} < a_{n-1}$ then $(a_{n},b_{n}) = (a_{n-1}+1,2b_{n-1})$. If $a_n = b_n$ then we are done.

In other words, at each step we double the lesser and add one to the greater of $(a,b)$. We stop when $a_n = b_n$, i.e. we reach a pair $(c,c)$.

My question is: for any $a, b$ are we guaranteed to terminate at a pair $(c,c)$?

Comment: Hmm, I see now that I possibly misunderstood the focus of your question. The word "for any" is ambiguous to me. Are you searching (at least) one solution *"where we reach a pair (c,c)"* ? Or are you asking "*for **each** a,b, are we guaranteed...?* "?

Comment: Well I was wondering if every such pair $(a,b)$ has a solution but it doesn't work except for certain values.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a pair of the form $(a, 2^ra - r)$, then you get $(2a, 2^ra- (r-1))$, ie a pair of the form $(a', 2^{r-1}a' -(r-1))$. So repeating the operation you will get a pair of the form $(c, c)$.

I claim this is the only way. Otherwise, we would have to get a pair of the form $(a, 2^ra - r)$ from something other than $(a/2, 2^ra - (r+1))$. The only possibility for this is $(a-1, \frac{2^ra - r}{2})$. But for $r\geq 2$, $a>0$ we have $\frac{2^ra - r}{2} > a$; when $r=1$ $2^ra - r$ is not divisible by 2; and when $r=0$ it's just $(a-1, a/2)$, so not actually different to the pair we know works.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the termination at $(c,c)$ occurs for every pair. I just started with $(4,3)$ and got the following matrix showing the trajectory of the first couple of iterations as result. Here each row is one iterate of the initial pair and the difference between the elements of the pair:
$$\small \begin{array} {rr|r}
 a & b & a-b \\
\hline
 4 & 3 & 1 \\ 
 5 & 6 & -1 \\ 
 10 & 7 & 3 \\ 
 11 & 14 & -3 \\ 
 22 & 15 & 7 \\ 
 23 & 30 & -7 \\ 
 46 & 31 & 15 \\ 
 47 & 62 & -15 \\ 
 94 & 63 & 31 \\ 
 95 & 126 & -31 \\ 
 190 & 127 & 63 \\ 
 191 & 254 & -63 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
 \end{array}$$
The differences (in the third column) follow an obvious pattern and without analyzing this in detail I'm confident that this initial pair of numbers has an infinite trajectory.

[update]
If we look at the numbers along the trajectory of iterations, then it seems that the following is important.
Assume $a_0 \lt b_0$ . Then let's write all iterations while $a_j \lt b_j$ as one step and we want

$$ a_1=a_0 \cdot 2^{k}  >  b_1=b_0 + k >b_0 + k-1 >  a_0 \cdot 2^{k-1} >a_0 $$

We see, that $b_1$ lies in the interval of $a_1 .. a_1/2$. The next iteration, to build $b_2 = 2^j \cdot b_1 > a_1 + j$  needs then only a $j$ smaller than $k$ and along further iterations the required exponent at $2$ converges to $1$. So in the long run the transformation reduces to $a_{k+1} = 2 \cdot a_k , b_{k+1}=b_k+1 $  and vice versa $a_{k+2} = a_{k+1}+1 , b_{k+2}=2 \cdot b_{k+1} $ .

I think, this is the crucial observation (and should be made more rigorous: there's a smallest $k$ from where the above rule is valid if not already $a=b$)

Then proceeding on this path, writing two steps  in one this is
 $$a_{k+2} = 2^1 \cdot a_k +1 \qquad \qquad b_{k+2}=2^1 \cdot b_k+2 \\
   a_{k+4} = 2^2 \cdot a_k +3 \qquad \qquad b_{k+4}=2^2 \cdot b_k+6 \\
   a_{k+6} = 2^3 \cdot a_k +7 \qquad \qquad b_{k+6}=2^3 \cdot b_k+14 \\
  $$ 
Generalizing this gives 
 $$a_{k+2r}+1 = 2^r \cdot (a_k+1) \\
 b_{k+2r}+2=2^r \cdot (b_k+2)$$

and this shows, that the differences $d_k=(b_k+2) - (a_k+1)$ expand to $d_{k+2r} = 2^r \cdot d_k$ *(if not $a_k - b_k=1$)*.
And if the differences change, then the trajectories of $(a_k,b_k)$ cannot be constant.
If $a_k - b_k = 1$ at some $k$ then all the further differences are $1$ as well.

Comment: All numbers of the form $(x,x+1)$ have a solution using 10 steps. Assume $a,b$, and $L$ doubles $a$ and adds 1 to $b$, while $R$ doubles $b$ and adds 1 to $a$, then the operations are $RRLLLLRLRR$ and the solution reaches the diagonal at $32x+68$. See a complete solution at http://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/2v6eaj/doubling_and_adding_1/

Comment: @Foo : ??? How can you begin on a pair $(a,b)=(x,x+1)$ with the transformation $R$ : because $x+1>x$ the OP's scheme requires that we begin with $L$ on this. Thus after the first step we have $(2x,x+2)$. Then we have to apply $R$ giving $(2x+1,2x+2)$. Then we have again $L$ and so on alternating $LRLRLRLR...$

Comment: That's why there's a separate solution for $k=1$. I didn't write the solution presented there down as a proof because I'm skeptical that there isn't a shorter method, but there is certainly a solution for $k=1$ as I listed above.

Comment: @Foo : in the Reddit-forum there is less restriction: it is not required that the $2x$-operation is ***always on the smaller*** number of the pair. So that is a different problem...

Comment: I see, I assumed this was the same question and missed the fact that this one was restricted to the smaller number. Makes sense and I agree, it does seem that not every pair is solvable in this manner.